# Seaborn is not setting its default color palette on import

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn

There are many links which state that Matplotlib's plots would look more pleasing due to seaborn's color palette just by importing seaborn like

```
import seaborn as sns
```

However, when I do this, the colors and formatting still looks like plain matlotlib defaults for both matplotlib's plot as well as that of seaborn. That is unless the command `sns.set()` is executed to force reset the seaborn's default palette.

Why is this happening and how to fix this?

**How seaborn was installed:**
This happens in my Ubuntu 14.04 running Anaconda, although seaborn was installed through `pip` since the Anaconda version in the system did not come with it preinstalled. I tried installing seaborn through `conda` for both my environments, `py27` and `py35`. Though the installation was successful, the import did not work, so I proceeded with `pip`.

Though seaborn works perfectly fine, both environments still import with the same unpleasing matplitlib default colours.

Comment: If you are using a somewhat new version of matplotlib, you can use matplotlib's styles to improve the look via `plt.style.use('ggplot')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using seaborn version 0.8 or higher. The [change log](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html) tells us:

> The default style is no longer applied when seaborn is imported. It is now necessary to explicitly call `set()` or one or more of `set_style()`, `set_context()`, and `set_palette()`. Correspondingly, the seaborn.apionly module has been deprecated.

There is a very good reason for this. Previously, just because you imported seaborn it would completely alter the matplotlib style, possibly even overwriting previously set matplotlib styles. Both is usually undesired.

As you found out yourself, you need to call `seaborn.set()` to get the default style of seaborn or use any other of the [seaborn styles](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html).

You can also use seaborn styles with matplotlib and not using seaborn at all. E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("seaborn-darkgrid")
```

or any other style from the [style sheet reference](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html)

Comment: That's a relief. I thought there was something wrong with my installation.